Is it possible to create Azure Devops Branch from a Branch that exists in another Azure DevOps repo
We have two repositories which each contain multiple branches.
For example we have repo called IndRepo, which has a branch called 'main'

I would like to copy the 'main' repo in IndRepo and paste it into the the repo called ADF_xxxx

I would like to know if it's possible to either 1) Copy the 'main' branch in IndRepo and paste it into the Repo ADG_xxxxxx and called it another or 2) Create a new branch in ADF_xxxx 'Based on' the the 'main' branch in IndRepo?

You could use a submodule.

Hi @DanielMann, thanks for getting in touch.  Can you please describe how to implement a submodule ?

You can easily find dozens of resources on how to implement submodules with a quick Google search; you don't need me to do it for you.
